# Keyboard Freezes with Wireless Use on HP Pavillion dm1

Tags: wireless, keyboard, freeze, broadcom, hp-pavilion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I recently bought an **HP Pavillion DM1** laptop for everyday use. To get the wireless card working, I had to install the proprietary **Broadcom** drivers.

However, this has created a problem: from time to time, the keyboard and touchpad freeze. The system is not frozen, and whatever was running keeps on running. If I connect an external keyboard/mouse to the system they work fine, and if I run

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

from a terminal, then the laptop's keyboard and touchpad regain their functionality.
If I switch of the wireless, this problem does not happen any more.

Similar problems have been posted elsewhere, but the solutions given have not worked for me. These normally include blacklisting modules in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly a bug, file an issue with launchpad using apport, specify that this is a kernel issue so it gathers all the necessary details. Thanks.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#Filing_bugs_when_off-line

```
apport-cli -f -p linux-generic --save bug.crash
ubuntu-bug -c bug.crash
```

Comment: I have to admit I'm not a Linux guru, can you provide me with some more instructions on how to do this? Or a link perhaps?
On a different note, do you think I stand a chance if I buy an external USB wireless adapter?

Comment: @MelvinGauci I have a TP-link TL-WN721N that works wonderfully on ubuntu

Comment: Another usb adapter working is anyone's guess, there is a hardware compatibility list on the ubuntu site. A simple google search will address that. You're going to get further, faster, if you start helping yourself opposed to waiting for elementary suggestions from others.